# Buying property in India: paying loan/mortgage

Tags: united-states, mortgage, real-estate, india

I am on a [H1B visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-1B_visa) in USA and thinking about buying property in India.

What is the best way to make payments from USA bank ac to pay loan/mortgage in India? Can I get tax relief for loan/mortgage payment in the USA tax return?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways, transfer funds using Wire service or use Remittance services offered by quite a few Banks. Deposit the funds into an Indian account and use it to pay the mortgage.

To may knowledge you will not be entitled to a tax relief in US or in India.